# Changing mouse tilt buttons behaviour

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, remapping, mouse-wheel

I've recently installed Ubuntu MATE 20.04 and one of my peripherals is a Razer Naga 2014. This has tilt buttons on the mousewheel, so I cant tilt it left or right. On Windows, I can remap this tilt buttons to anything I want, so I was looking to do the same in Ubuntu.

The problem right now is: those tilt buttons behave exactly like the scroll up and scroll down on the mousewheel. For example, if I tilt the mouse left, Firefox scrolls the page down, and does the opposite if I tilt the mouse right.

I've looked here that the solution might be playing around with `xbindings`. I ran `xev` and it told me that indeed mousewheel and tilt buttons are behaving the same. For example, both tilt left and scroll down return the same text:

```
ButtonRelease event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0x292, subw 0x0, time 12969025, (72,107), root:(73,163),
    state 0x1010, button 5, same_screen YES
```

So, I think what I have to do is mapping the tilt left and right to something else, like F13 and F14, so I can use `xbindkeys` to remap it if I need to, like, for example, a specific game. However, I don't have a clue how to do it. Perhaps it has something to do with `xmodmap` or something.

I don't know if it helps, but that's what `xinput -list` prints:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Naga 2014                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Naga 2014                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga 2014                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga 2014                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I don't know why it shows 2 Razer Naga as pointers. I've disabled id=11 and the mouse seemed to work flawlessly. If I disable id=10, it stops working. `xinput -get-button-map 10` shows `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. If I do the same for 11, it shows `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I've researched a little more. If I do `xinput --query-state 10 | grep down` while pressing the left mouse button, I get:

```
    button[1]=down
```

However, if I do the same thing pressing tilt left or tilt right, nothing shows up. If I remove the `grep`, `xinput` says all mouse buttons are up.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a faulty hardware. I've booted in Windows and the same thing was happening. I've installed Synapse, remapped the keys and apparently it's working. I had no idea these configurations were saved in the hardware, and openrazer or razercfg can't change it, only the official program can.

Comment: Hi, I also have the Naga Trinity and my tilt buttons are not working under Ubuntu... do you think you could help me out to explain how did you do it?